# Connection aborted while fetching data from Wikipedia

Tags: python, python-2.7, connection

I wrote a python script to fetch definitions and URLs of list of items (I am using a long list with no less than 3000 items).

The script was working fine, I used it several times, but suddenly I started to get the following error:

```
    ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

here is the full traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Wiki.py", line 41, in <module>
    page = wikipedia.page(item)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 270, in page
    results, suggestion = search(title, results=1, suggestion=True)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in       __call__
ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
     raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 737, in _wiki_request
r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
```

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the while installing the regular `requests` python library, it does not install the necessary packages to cope for https connections. Install these by:

`pip install requests[security]`